# What does android call differently if OPEN or DONE is selected after app install?

Tags: android, installation, resume

I would really like to understand this in a hope that I can fix this problem which I have spent countless hours on...

I understand the circumstances surrounding the behaviour of the problem, but have no idea where to fix it, though I guess it will be in manifest some where...

If I install my APK and then select 'DONE' after the install is complete, my app resume functionality works fine!  But if I select 'OPEN' then the app resume functionality will never resume to the last used screen, it just keeps returning to whatever the launcher screen is..

and there is more..

when I select OPEN, but then access task manager and END the app process, then launch it from the ICON in the home screen... the resume works perfectly again..

It's driving me crazy.. I have seen some people comment about this exact problem but have never seen an answer to go with it!  I was hoping if I can understand what OPEN does differently to DONE then selecting the icon on the home screen to open the app, then I / we might be able to finally figure it out!

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer .. or what there is of it.

Seems like I am among many others who lost countless, countless hours trying to fix this one when it is reported as an android OS bug which is extremely hard to fix.  Here are two links to androids official bug issues regarding this particular bug.

You can go through the replies and test various fixes, but unfortunately the bug is still not fixed from androids side (apparently).

Just hope this helps save SOME PEOPLE a lot of time if they can read this early on!!

(Basically the android OS gets confused in some instances when installing the app and causes this behaviour).

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2373  (original issue)

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26658  (follow up of the exact same issue as was still not fixed since 2373...)

Answer (score -1):

Please add code to onCreate

```
if (isTaskRoot()) {
            final Intent intent = getIntent();
            final String intentAction = intent.getAction();
            if (!intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) &&
                    intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
```